# Vegetarian food in Morocco

Tags: food-and-drink, morocco, dietary-restrictions, marrakech

I am visiting Morocco (Fez, Marrakesh, Aït Benhaddou and Meknes) in December. I am vegetarian (no animal products except dairy). Can I survive in these cities?

Comment: I would edit the last part of your question and just ask something like "Can a vegetarian survive Morocco by visiting grocery stores?"

Comment: I for one would like to know in general, not just supermarkets.

Comment: Yes, If you love Tagin then always ask for Veg. Tagin.

Answer (score 10):

My boyfriend and I (both vegetarian) were in Morocco for 3 weeks with our bikes. We were visiting Marrakech, Agadir, Essaouira from the big cities and many small villages in Atlas and Anti-Atlas. Though we don't speak Arabic and French (we have only learned some words) we NEVER had any problems with vegetarian food.

Mostly we got some vegan Tajine, with different ingredients. We also never have to explain what we mean with "vegetarian" (so they never wanted to give us some fish, for example)!

Answer (score 6):

You can survive, as a vegetarian, in most of the known world, Morocco included.

Meat eating historically has never been common nor cheap, and today it is so just because it's been one of the cultural exports of the USA during WW2 and now we feel like it's the norm, so we are scared to travel somewhere and not be able to avoid meat.

The truth is, aside from the US, people eat and cook much more vegetable than they realise. Moroccans love their meat, but they have plenty of vegetables-only recipes too.

Comment: I think that the answer, while accurate isn't entirely complete. The bigger problem for tourists is to communicate and explain their dietary restrictions. Could you also add some common morrocan staples that the OP could safely look out for in restaurants or with street vendors.

Comment: Vegetarian couscous is the way to go.

Comment: I read that couscous is typically cooked in animal fat.

Comment: couscous is often only available on Fridays as well.

Comment: In Morocco most of dishes are Vegetarian, even those where we use meat can be prepared without meat. @Simon, you can get you couscous all the week days.

Comment: A problem that I found in Turkey is that although vegetarian dishes may be common, they are less common in restaurants.  It seemed that people splashed out in restaurants which meant meat dishes and hence they dominated the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I visited Morocco a few months back. There are not too many vegetarian options but still, it's not too difficult to survive. **Veg Tajine** and  **Couscous** are the most common options.

For better Information, Please visit my channel:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJLzR83mYNw&list=PLeolEzFfNLHpWSNodeiy08a7JXCmzoshs

[image]

[image]

*Images taken from Google

Comment: If you want to use the photos, please use ones with full disclosure of the maker and the rights.